# vue computed property not able to get data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently experiencing an issue where the `computed()` property is not able to get data. Although data was already initiated in `created()` property. Am I doing it wrong? Please advise how I can fix this issue.

```
const randomPlayers = {
    template:
    `
    <input type="text" v-model="search_player">
    <div v-for="player in modPlayers" v-if="list_of_random_players!=null">
        <p>{{player.firstname}}</p>
        <p>{{player.lastname}}</p>
    <div>

    `,
    props: ['data'],
    data (){
        return{
        list_of_random_players: null,
        search_player: null
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.get_random_players()
    },
    computed: {
        modPlayers(){
            return this.list_of_random_players.filter( person => {
              return !this.search_player ||
                ( person.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search_player.toLowerCase()) > -1 || person.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search_player.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        get_random_players: function(){
            $.post(
                url:'random_url'
                data: {
                    players: data
                }
            ).done((success)=>{
                this.list_of_random_players: JSON.parse(success)
            })fail((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following two errors:

(1) `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null`

(2) `TypeError: this.list_of_random_players.filter is not a function`

Comment: First, if you initialize data as function i.e `data()` you have to return an object. Then you pass `{ players: data }` in your post request but where `data` comes from ?

Comment: @Sovalina, I got it from props. I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html): "When a Vue instance is created, it adds all the properties found in its data **object** to Vue’s reactivity system. When the values of those properties change, the view will “react”, updating to match the new values."

So `data` is a function that returns an **object** but as mentioned by @Sovalina you are not returning it so you cannot access its properties. You need to add `return` and change `null` to `[]`:

```
data() {
    return {

          list_of_random_players: [],
           search_player: []
    }
 },
```

or you can do without `return` and like a regular object:

```
data: {
     list_of_random_players: [],
         search_player: []
  }
```

When your Vue component is used multiple times, it is better to use it like a function(first case).

"When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object. Why? Because there will be many instances created using the same definition. If we still use a plain object for data, that same object will be shared by reference across all instance created! By providing a data function, every time a new instance is created we can call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data."
Reference:[link](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

It might be just a typo but you need to add `:` to `methods` as well.

Comment: I am getting the following error:

`this.list_of_random_players.filter` is not a function. I think it is still null even after the created() was ran

Comment: I actually have two error:
(1) `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null`
(2) `TypeError: this.list_of_random_players.filter is not a function`

Comment: Then you need to debug your code to see what you are getting back from the REST call.Another thing is try changing the initialization of your data properties from `null` to `[]`

Comment: That was it. I just had to change `null` to `[]` to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Then I will update my answer accordingly. Happy to hear that